# Redirect a video monitor

Tags: video, wireless-router, video-streaming, video-capture, video-playback

I don't know a lot about the internet, nor video, but I thought I'd ask here anyway.

I have an old Motorola video monitor that is "hard coded" to send all audio and video to the company server, though I am told they don't support that model anymore. I would then log on to their server to watch it. They suggest I buy a new one. I'd rather send the video/audio steam to a new router and then somehow use my laptop to watch any video. This would all happen without using the real internet, though I do have wifi from another router.

Would something like this work? Any suggestions? I am familiar with c, c++, Python, lisp, and assembly but i doubt that helps much.... Probably the c/c++.....

Thanks!

Comment: Do you perhaps mean 'hard wired' as opposed to 'hard coded'?  For instance there is a NTSC style video cable running from a camera to a capture card on a server?

Comment: Well it was in quotes because i don't know how. But it is a wireless camera. Though set up requires a laptop and Internet.

Comment: Do you have a model number of what you are describing?

Comment: Yes, its mbp85connect.

Comment: Might be mbp65connect, the box is worn. I bought it used

Comment: There is a baby monitor camera with that model number.  It might be locked to a cloud type service.  like slingbox and roku are.  I hate things that can become bricks if some company somewhere decides to shut down their infrastructure.  for sale at http://www.amazon.com/Motorola-MBP85CONNECT-Wi-Fi-Monitor-Camera/dp/B00TYLD02Q

Comment: Aahhh... Well i just bought it from a sorta-friend yesterday. Maybe i should have researched it more but I knew I didn't know enough about these things ha ha